# Disabling button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, button

I need to disable a RectButton button in react native, has anyone done this or do you know how I can do it?

I know that in ActivityButton you can disable it, does RectButton have the same behavior?

Comment: At least indicate which library you are using please. Both components do not come from vanilla RN.

Comment: stylized components for styling

Comment: can you please provide some code examples to understand your scenario. Because the RectButton and ActivityButton are not common components. Add some code snippet.